# Rendering turkish characters with DOMPDF

Tags: php, character-encoding, dompdf, turkish

I am using DOMPDF library to generate pdf files. The issue is rendering turkish characters.

It is not rendering all turkish characters. For example, for word "Oranı", it displays "OranÄ±".

Any idea how to fix this?

I tried with all in-built font families like "dejavu", "helvetica", "arial".

Configuration:

In DOMPDF config file (dompdf_config.inc.php)

```
def("DOMPDF_UNICODE_ENABLED", true);
mb_internal_encoding('UTF-8');
```

In my html,

```
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
        <style>
        body { font-family: "arial"; }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <--- my content --->
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What is the output of mb_internal_encoding() ?

Comment: You need to add the character encoding utf8 in the html before rendering to PDF also there are some config as mentioned by @CBergau , it should be utf8

Comment: Encoding is set to utf-8, in both HTML meta and in php

Comment: Maybe this issue helps you? https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf/issues/626

Comment: They finally did it using another libary mPDF. I want to use DOMPDF only.

Comment: Is this a static file or database-driven content? dompdf version? MBString PHP extension is enabled? You'll need to use a font that supports your character set, which in the case of a clean install of dompdf is the pre-installed DejaVu fonts (e.g. `DejaVu Sans`).